# Apply svg transform matrix to text font-size

Tags: svg, transform, inkscape

I have an svg text element with the transform attribute. I need to apply the transform to the text. I was able to get the correctly transformed x,y values of the element by applying the matrix to the coordinates. But there's no way I can apply the matrix to a single value (i.e. text size)? I tried using the size twice for applying the transform but that does not produce right result.

So how to apply the svg transform matrix to text font-size?

I am using Inkscape `inkex.transform` modules `apply_to_point` function.

Update: Here is the Inkscape code snippet:

```
selections = self.svg.selection
for s in selections:
    transStr = s.get('transform')
    if(transStr is not None):
        tr = inkex.transform.Transform(transStr)
        x = s.get('x')
        y = s.get('y')
        if(x is not None and y is not None):
            # apply transform to coordinates
            co = tr.apply_to_point((x, y))
            s.pop('transform')
            s.set('x', str(co[0]))
            s.set('y', str(co[1]))
            stStr = s.get('style')
            if(stStr is not None):
                style = inkex.styles.Style.parse_str(stStr)
                sizeStr = style.get('font-size')
                if(sizeStr is not None):
                    m = re.match('([0-9.]+)(.*)', sizeStr)
                    if(len(m.groups()) > 1):
                        size = m[1]
                        # apply transform to size 
                        # but this returns a tuple of 2 
                        # we need only one. 
                        # And even taking one element from tuple
                        # this doesn't work.
                        style['font-size'] = str(tr.apply_to_point((size, size)))
                s.set('style', style)
```

Comment: add the transform to the text element. If you [add an example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) of what you have so far perhaps we can fix it.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks. I have updated the thread with code sample. Please check the comments.

Comment: What you are trying makes no sense **mathematically**. A general afine transformation, as represented by a `transform` matrix can be [decomposed](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-primitives) into a combination of translation, rotation and scale, but there is never any guarantee that the scale will be uniform in all directions. The most basic example is `matrix(0.5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)`, equivalent to `scale(0.5, 1)`. It squashes the text to half its width while the height remains the same. There simply is no font size that would produce that effect.